# Is it possible for someone to experience amnesia immediately after a traumatic event?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I was wondering if at the end of a painful experience, it is possible for a person to forget what happened before the traumatic event. Specifically, can the retrograde amnesia happen instantly after the traumatic event, or does it take months, or even years, to forget about that event?

I've been documenting about combat fatigue, and how it could affect soldiers in many ways, including personality troubles, inability to fight or physically shoot, amnesia...

So my question is: Can someone instantly forget an atraumatic event, or does it take time before they start to face major psychological effects such as amnesia?

Comment: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/conditions/dissociative-amnesia Dissociative amnesia would be a good place to start. Perhaps even Dissociative Identity Disorder.

Answer (score -1):

According to Potter-Efron’s rage blackout rubric, these bouts of unconsciousness can last anywhere from seconds to hours, leaving the individual exhausted with no memory of their actions3.
Learn more:

1. globalnews.ca
2. medicinenet.com
3. vice.com
   Causes can stem from drugs, alcohol, PTSD, medication side effects...
   I have personally blacked out a number of times after getting extremely angry.

Comment: Can you provide actual references (rather than news outlets)?  Answers are expected to be backed up with credible evidence.